# Is there a good yaml library for Android?

Tags: java, android, yaml

Is there a java yaml library as good as snakeyaml for Android? (Or is anyone successfully using snakeyaml on Android already?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not think you can use SnakeYaml on Android without modifications (at least now).

By default, SnakeYaml uses `Introspector` to get `PropertyDescriptors` for classes, and as I can see `java.beans.Introspector` is not available on Android. But there is `BeanAccess.FEILD` mode in the SnakeYaml which uses fields to dump/load beans. That mode uses only `java.lang.reflect` classes available on Android.

So, with some modifications it might work. But I need to try it to be sure.

**Added**

Now android compatible version of SnakeYaml can be build using :

`mvn -Pandroid clean package`

**Update (March 2017):**

Starting from 1.18 android build is in central. You can add dependency into your pom.xml like this

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
  <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
  <version> VERSION </version>
  <classifier>android</classifier>
</dependency>
```

or in your `build.gradle` like this:

```
implementation "org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.18:android"
```

Comment: Thank you. That's helpful to know. If you do try it, please update us here. I'll wait for you to try it first because I am starting with zero experience.

Comment: Yep. It did not build without modifications. But... this one should work: http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/downloads/detail?name=snakeyaml-android-1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar Remember it uses Fields on classes, not setters and getters!!! No matter what `BeanAccess.xxx` mode you set it is always `BeanAccess.FIELD`. Please try it. I have created an issue about Android  http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/issues/detail?id=92 Feel free to put comments there.

Comment: Thank you for making that modified version available!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should at least try directly snakeyaml. For this kind of library it's highly probable that the needed Java API set is available in Android.

If it does not work, you may try to import snakeyaml source code in an android project and see what doesn't compile. With a little luck it will be possible to work around the missing APIs.

Comment: Thanks for your encouragement. With my limited experience (no Android development yet), I was hoping someone else would have already tried this. But I do like snakeyaml, so it would be great if it works on Android.

Answer (score 0):

From the answer [How do I convert from YAML to JSON in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744216/how-do-i-convert-from-yaml-to-json-in-java)

```
String convertYamlToJson(String yaml) {
    ObjectMapper yamlReader = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    Object obj = yamlReader.readValue(yaml, Object.class);

    ObjectMapper jsonWriter = new ObjectMapper();
    return jsonWriter.writeValueAsString(obj);
}
```

Requires:

```
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.7.4'
```