# How could you implement `kubectl apply -f stuff.yaml` with the java Kubernetes Client

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to execute an operation on Kubernetes like `kubectl apply -f stuff.yaml` from a java program. I don't want to invoke kubectl from my Java program, instead, I would like to use the Java [Kubernetes client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java). After looking at the API classes in the project I wasn't able to figure what methods I could use to achieve functionality similar to `kubectly apply`.

Does anyone have any pointers on how to achieve it?

Comment: YAML config files are a thing entirely handled by `kubectl`, not by the Kubernetes API itself.  If you want to interpret these YAML files, you're going to need to reimplement chunks of `kubectl` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no methods per se or silver bullet really, essentially what you are trying to do is almost trying to rewrite `kubectl` in Java.

You should be able to achieve it decoding the YAML using something like [Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38274671/2989261) or [SnakeYAML](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/src/default/) and use all the different components in the [Kubernetes client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java), like Create namespaces, pods, deployments, etc.

You can also do a [brute force](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/) approach through the `kube-apiserver` on `https://kube-apiserver-address:6443/api/...` by sending an authenticated/authorized GET/POST/DELETE request with a JSON payload which you can get from converting the YAML to JSON (and perhaps a bit of cleanup) You can use something like the [Apache HTTP client library](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) or [Jersey](https://jersey.github.io/).