# Validate JSON data against Yaml shema

Tags: java, yaml, jsonschema

I have a java object (let's name it JsonValidator) that can be configured in YAML file.
I would like to describe a schema of JSON objects in YAML notation [something like this](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.3.md#schemaObject)

And then I need to validate JSON objects according to the schema. Does anybody know any Java libs I can use or any examples?

Thanks

Comment: OpenAPI and JSON Schema are (currently) two different things. From OpenAPI 3.1 onward, it is planned to fully support 100% of the JSON Schema Draft 2019-09 (plus a few things on top). If you only want to validate JSON objects, I’d suggest you stick to a pure JSON Schema approach – preferably the latest Draft 2019-09 if you’re free to choose. As per `erosb`’s answer: the rest is then only a matter of converting YAML to JSON.

Comment: "What library can I used" is considered off topic on Stack Overflow. Please do ask questions such as "How can I do X?" though, or if you have JSON Schema questions, join our active and helpful slack server

Answer (score 0):

The schema of a json document can be defined using [json schema](http://json-schema.org/) (actually, OpenAPI uses a custom flavor of json schema). It is essentially a json document defining the structure of an other json document. There are a few [java implementations](http://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validator-java) out there. If you want to stick to YAML for defining the schema, then will first need to convert YAML to JSON and then use the  json schema validator, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744216/how-do-i-convert-from-yaml-to-json-in-java) for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some Java validators for JSON Schema [here](https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validator-java).

Comment: That same link was provided by `erosb` along with some explanation addressing the YAML part of the question, which is not considered here.